# Deleting and updating on different LPARs

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, rpgle, control-language

Is it possible to compute a file member removal in a rpgle program from a development lpar.

```
   eg: RMVM FILE(LIB/FILE1) MBR(PAR1981181)
```

and performing updates on a different file in a different lpar altogether?

```
 UPDATE "SCDTA.CORP"/AR#RMTPRL9 
SET SENTFLAG = ' ', DATESENT = '0001-01-01', TIMESENT = '00:00:00', XMITT# = 0, LOCATION =   'PACI175A', ARBATCH# = ' ' 
 WHERE LOCATION = 'PACI173A' AND ARBATCH# = 'PAR1981181'
```

How exactly can one perform setting of lpars in one single program?Is this possible.
Please guide.

Answer (score 2):

These operations can be be done by using [DDM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/ddp/rbae5intrdf.htm) and [RUNRMTCMD](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/cl/runrmtcmd.htm) to link the LPAR's as remote systems.

For more information see:

- [Distributed database programming](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/ddp/rbal1kickoff.htm)
- [Operating remote systems](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/ddp/rbal1opremote.htm)

Comment: Appreciate the help. How could I possibly incorporate this as a programming construct in a RPG or CL?

Comment: @learning_fly The documentation will guide you through the details but the gist of it is to create a DDM connection between the two LPAR's and then use the DDM file for SQL execution and `QCMDEXEC` for command execution of the `RMVM` command wrapped in a `RUNRMTCMD` command.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on release 7.1 and have the appropriate PTF group loaded, then you can use 3-part naming in SQL. This let's you qualify a table reference with the database (ie. RDB directory entry) and schema (ie. library).

For example:

```
UPDATE OTHERSYS.SCDTA_CORP.AR#RMTPRL9 
  SET SENTFLAG = ' ' 
    , DATESENT = '0001-01-01'
    , TIMESENT = '00:00:00'
    , XMITT#   = 0
    , LOCATION = 'PACI175A'
    , ARBATCH# = ' ' 
  WHERE LOCATION = 'PACI173A'
    AND ARBATCH# = 'PAR1981181'
```